# C++ Winsock Determine HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: c++, https, winsock

I've just started studying Winsocks and I've a simple question for you: how can I determine if the connection to a server must take place over a HTTP or HTTPS connection?
Let's say I want to connect to randomsite.random, how can I know what kind of connection I need? I know that for HTTP I must connect to port 80, while for HTTPS is needed 443, but how can I determine WHEN is needed a HTTPS connection?

Thank you for the attention!

Answer (score 3):

The same way a web browser decides: Based on the URL you are trying to load. In a web browser, the URL begins with `http` or `https`, which is used to determine whether an SSL connection should be used. This is also used to determine the port if no port number is specified in the URL.

Many sites offer both a secure and a non-secure version. Some offer only a secure version, but still run a non-secure server which issues a redirect to the URL of the secure version. If you implement following of redirects, you don't need to worry about which version to use: it will happen automatically.

Answer (score 3):

This is usually a function of the site you are connecting to.

If the site requires a HTTPS connection, then if you connect over HTTP you will get a redirect response code with a HTTPS URL.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's not always port 80 and port 443. Secondly, you won't establish successful communication if you use the wrong communication protocol. As said in another answer, if you try to connect via HTTP to an HTTPS server, it will give you a redirect response code with an HTTPS URL.

Most of the time, you have this information before-hand!